# Xcode 5 - Switched to Landscape orientation, content not centered anymore

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I switched to landscape orientation and I have a button and slider in my very simple app. In the live view in Xcode, the content is exactly in the middle of the screen (snapped into place). However when I run the app, the content is slightly shifted to the right in the Simulator. Anybody have any idea how to fix this?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/l2p5l.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/TbaXG.jpg

Comment: Please add some code / a screenshot of your storyboard or xib / tell us if you're using AutoLayout. We cannot help with so little information.

Comment: This is one of the many things Autolayout solves. An internet search will show many tutorials on the subject. Or follow a course like `Developing iOS 7 Apps on iPhone and iPad` on iTunesU in iTunes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using auto-layout try to add Constraint like this.
Click the issues Button [image: The third from left]

[image]

Then click on 'Reset to suggested constraints in Window'.